# Chrome Extension - Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 1, column: 2, Dictionary keys must be quoted

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I wanted to build my first extension so I copied some code from an online tutorial (https://www.sitepoint.com/create-chrome-extension-10-minutes-flat/) I found:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "GTmetrix Analyzer Plugin",
  "description": "This extension will analyze a page using GTmetrix",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

When I try to upload the unpacked extension I always get this error:

**Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 1, column: 2, Dictionary keys must be quoted.**

What exactly can I change to make it work?

(Please give me exact instructions, I'm a newbie!)

Comment: The posted json is fine so I guess there's a problem with the actual file. Maybe an incorrect encoding. Use any official [demo extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) as a base and modify it to your needs.

Comment: I second @wOxxOm's statement. The JSON is valid. Are you sure this is the JSON *currently* being used?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and help! It worked after i downloaded the example file and exchanged the code, THANKS!!!!